# sqli take only first value in query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building a music player trying to print only  the first row of my database to use it as the first song of the playlist that will be currently playing and the others are going to be stored in a `JQuery ListView`. I am getting this error code:

**Notice:** Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\Users\Xaimer\Desktop\Interactive\USBWebserver v8.6\root\playlist.php on line 39.

Line 39 is the if statement

```
<?php
echo'<p>Playlist</p>';
$sql="SELECT * FROM co1706assigment.tracks INNER JOIN co1706assigment.playlist ON tracks.track_id=playlist.track_id ";
$playlistcounter=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) FROM co1706assigment.playlist")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))&&($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($playlistcounter))) // it takes all the results from sql query
{
    if($playlistcounter<2)
    {
        echo'<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
                            <li><img id="song" src="'.$row["image"].'"/><p class="name">Track Name: </p>'.$row["name"].'
                            <p class="name">Album Name: </p>'.$row["album"].'
                            <p class="name">Sample</p>
                            <audio controls>
                            <source src="'.$row["sample"].'" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </audio>
                            </li>
                            </ul>';
    }
}
echo'<p> My Playlist</p>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) // it takes all the results from sql query
{
   echo'<ul data-role="listview">
  <li><a href="TrackDescription.php" data-ajax="false">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>
  </ul>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` look to
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

OR

use it like this `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){}`